# How can go in last activity with resume button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-studio-2.0

My app works fine, but my purpose is that when I close the app then run it again, my app opens at the last activity. I want when I open again main activity become to show and if I clicked resume then last activity open. So I have 4 `Activity` called `Main Activity (my main)` , `p1` ,`p2`, `p3`:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);



        Button resume=(Button)findViewById(R.id.resume);
        Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);

        resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (!isTaskRoot()
                        && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                        && getIntent().getAction() != null
                        && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

                    finish();
                    return;
                }


            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
          }
      });

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                moveTaskToBack(true);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="resume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resume"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="next"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="exit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

p1:

```
public class p1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p1);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.home);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,p2.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        }
    }
```

p1 XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/next"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="page 1"/>
    <Button
        android:text="go in main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and p2, p3 like p1

for example :    when I am in p2 then click in go to main and in main when click exit and re run my app , my app open in p2 i want when i re run app main activity open if i clicked resume then p2 come to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open main activity when relaunch you should call

```
private void FinishActivity(){
this.finish();
}
```

in your onClick events after `startActivity(intent);`

for resume your activity  store current activity class as String to shared preference

Call below method in your code before `moveTaskToBack(true);`

```
    private void storeCurrentActivity(){ 
        SharedPreferences myPref =getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF",            Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPref.edit(); 
        editor.clear(); 
        String packageName = this.getPackageName(); 
        String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); 
        editor.putString("lastactivity",packageName+"."+className); 
        editor.commit(); 
}
```

and store result in to a shared preference

when you comeback to your application just check the SharedPreference

use below code in your main activity after `setContentView(R.layout.main_page);`

```
String lastActivity= getLastActivity();
try {
            Intent fooActivity = new Intent(this,Class.forName(lastActivity))
            startActivity(fooActivity)
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

place this method in your MainActivity

```
   private String getLastActivity(){
                  SharedPreferences myPref = =   getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  String lastActivity= myPref.getString("lastactivity","");

        }
```

this may help you

**Solution For this specific problem**

Replace your home button action with below code

```
home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                storeCurrentActivity();
                this.finish();

            }
        });
```

the above code will store your actiivty,ie if you are in activity p1,it will store p1 as last activity

also please remove `onResume` Action

Comment: can u explain it from my code ? so i put private void store Current Activity in my go in main button ? and another codes ... just tell me where i must use this code in my code please thanks

Comment: you should call 'storeCurrentActivity()' all the time you are exiting from your application.

Comment: use `String lastActivity= getLastActivity();
try {
            Intent fooActivity = new Intent(this,Class.forName(lastActivity))
            startActivity(fooActivity)
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } ` in resume Button onclick.

Comment: still have problem . can u give me your mail ? i send this app for u then fix it and resend me ... if it possible for you . thanks

Comment: what are the problems you are facing? can you give more details then i can suggest some solution,i think it is better to discuss here because so many experienced developers are watching these activities ,they can also help us.

Comment: first of all your code have so many errors i fix that errors but still not working . are you test this code ? are you work with android studio or eclipse ? because i work with android studio . and your explain so confuse if u want help explain your code with my code . but thanks any way friend

Comment: first of all, i would like to know my concept is useful for you or not,Error in code problem have solution in android studio.can you give the error texts

Comment: if u want help just tell me where i must put your codes in my codes

Comment: are you read the explanation i provided in my answer?, i edited it so many times check it

Comment: i put codes in blow but resume button not work . have some suggest ?

Comment: what you mean by that code in onResume? can you explain

Comment: i do Ismael Di Vita way

Comment: after some try i solve my problem . look at my answer :) . thanks for help me

Comment: hi look at my answer in below its work fine but problem here when i stop app and relaunch again seems Shared Preferences lost value itself . i use editor.apply(); but still when stop app and lunch again had that problem :(

Comment: dude i use your way but resume button not work . its mean when click resume button do noting ...

Comment: in your below answer p1 ,p2 , p3 home button click implementation still same,change to my implemetation

Comment: @erfan check your below answer,i modifies it.

Comment: look at my answer in below i do with your way but resume button not work , look at and tell me where wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118988/discussion-between-clifford-and-erfan).

Answer (score 0):

I will use the Clifford's response to propose a solution for you, since you could not understand his answer, although it was very clear to me.

The method above will store the activity on SharedPreferences

```
private void storeCurrentActivity(){
             SharedPreferences myPref =getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPref.edit();
             editor.putString("lastactivity",this.getClass().getSimpleName());
             editor.commit();
}
```

Put this method and call him in all onResume in every Activity, except on Main:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        storeCurrentActivity();
    }
```

In your resume button, just call the last saved Activity

```
resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lastActivity= myPref.getString("lastactivity","");
        try {
            Intent fooActivity = new Intent(this,Class.forName(lastActivity))
            startActivity(fooActivity)
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
 });
```

Comment: thanks for answering Ismael so i do according to your explain but still have two problem : 1)resume button not work . 2)when relaunch app Main activity(main page) not loaded just load last activity when i was and clicked go to main .

Comment: for example if in p2 click in go to main and exit from app . when relaunch app p2 loaded first not main activity

Comment: after some try i fix problem 2 which mean when relaunch app main activity loaded with this code in main activity in Manifast :   android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 0):

so after some try this was my answer of my question
Main activity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page);



    Button resume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);


    resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String lastActivity= getLastActivity();

            try {
                if(!lastActivity.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"previous activity :"+lastActivity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent fooActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Class.forName(lastActivity));
                    startActivity(fooActivity);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no previous activity !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
    });
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
private String getLastActivity(){
    SharedPreferences myPref =    getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lastActivity= myPref.getString("lastactivity","");

    return lastActivity;
}


}
```

p1,p2,p3 :

```
public class p1 extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.p1);

            Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
            Button home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.home);

            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(p1.this, p2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(p1.this,MainActivity.class);
                    storeCurrentActivity();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    p1.this.finish();


                }
            });

    }
        private void storeCurrentActivity(){
            SharedPreferences myPref =getSharedPreferences("APP_SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            String packageName = this.getPackageName();
            String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            editor.putString("lastactivity",packageName+"."+className);
            editor.commit();
        }


    }
```