# How to save intent from start Activity for Result using Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, uri

I want to save an intent using Shared Preferences. I tried within startActivityforResult like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            String uriString = data.toUri(0); 
            editor.putString("Contacts_app", uriString);
            editor.commit();
```

and retrieve like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
String contactsApp = settings.getString("Contacts_app", null);
try {
    telApp = Intent.parseUri(contactsApp, 0);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this is not working. is there a mistake or another option how I can fix the Problem?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609179/how-can-go-in-last-activity-with-resume-button/38610185#38610185 may help you

Comment: @pskink the insert intent and the retrieve intent. So I think the parseUri

Comment: instead of commit() try apply()